# Showing $\exp$ is complex differentiable at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm revising and have come across a question where I'm given the limit definition of a function being complex differentiable at a point, and am asked to use the inequality $|\exp(w)-1-w|≤|w|^2$, if $|w|≤1$, to show that $\exp$ is complex differentiable at $0$.  I know $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$ and I know how to prove differentiability of $\exp$ for each point in the complex plane using the Cauchy Riemann equations.  I know this is pretty basic basic, but would appreciate a hint!

Comment: **Hint:** Try dividing your inequality by $|w|$.

Comment: All you need to prove is that the limit $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{{e^w  - e^0 }}{{w - 0}}
$$ exists. Prove that it is $1$ using the given inequality.

Comment: Before proving differentiabilty of the exponential there are very few properties of the exponential function at our disposal. I don't think the suggested inequality is a  good way of proving differentiabilty.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I agree, and I think what the question should be is something like: if $f(0)=1$ and $f$ satisfies the inequality $|f(w)-1-w|\leqslant |w|^2$ then $f'(0)$ exists.